# Dataframe value changes based on a condition doesn't work even though printing it does

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame with Date, Time, Flow. I can print selections of it and it grabs the corresponding data correctly, but when I try to change the values, it does nothing.

The print statement below selects the corresponding data correctly.

```
df["Flow"][ df["Date"] == "2022-02-23" ]
```

The reassignment below does nothing.

```
df["Flow"][ df["Date"] == "2022-02-23" ] = 100
```

But if I take the selection out as seen below, it correctly changes the value.

```
df["Flow"] = 100
```

I'd like to add more conditions, but in all combinations of the other conditions, the print always works and the reassignment doesn't. Is there something basic I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this and see if it works:

```
df.loc[df["Date"] == "2022-02-23", "Flow"] = 100
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a list comprehension:
`df["Flow"] = [100 if date == "2022-02-23" else df["Flow"][i]  for i, date in enumerate(df["Date"])]`